# asp.net mvc - Inserting multiple records in the third table having foreign keys to parent using entity framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am trying to learn how to use Entity Framework 6 with an already created database, without creating an `.edmx` file, i.e, using the `DbContext` and POCO classes.

These are my model classes:

```
[Table("Category")]
public class Category
{
   [Key]
   public long CategoryID { get; set; }
   public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}

[Table("RegistrationForm")]
public class RegistrationForm
{
    [Key]
    public int RegistrationID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
    public int Country { get; set; }        
    public string Email { get; set; }       
    public string Phone { get; set; }  
}   

[Table("RegistrationCategory")]
public class RegistrationCategory
{
    [Key]
    public long RegistrationCategory { get; set; }
    public long RegistrationID { get; set; }//Foreign key to RegistrationID in RegistrationForm table in database
    public long CategoryID { get; set; }//Foreign key to CategoryID in Category table in database
}
```

My `DbContext` class:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<RegistrationForm> RegistrationForm { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<RegistrationCategory> RegistrationCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Here I want to use the default model builder of `DbContext`.User can select multiple categories in the registration screen so the `RegistrationCategory` table will have multiple records for each registration. Therefore `RegistrationForm` and `RegistrationCategory` are in a `one-to-many` relationship.

How to write foreign key mappings between the above mentioned models?

How to bind data from `Category` table data in the `mvc view`(`listbox`) so that we can save one record in `RegistrationForm` table and multiple records in `RegistrationCategory` table without using loops (using mappings between the c# models) in Entity Framework 6?

Comment: where are your navigation properties?

Comment: @Claies I am still very new to entity framework so I don't know how navigation properties work...

Comment: It looks like `RegistrationCategory` is a join table that doesn't have it's own properties? it doesn't really look like it even needs a model.

Comment: @Claies yes there are no properties, it is a relation table between `Category` and `RegistrationForm` which will multiple records for each category selected for a registration..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database schema that you have here is a Many to Many relationship between `RegistrationForm` and `Category`, with a join table.  The `RegistrationCategory` Table is not necessary to be modeled in Entity Framework at all.  You will need to use Entity Framework Fluent API to generate the correct mappings.

First, your `RegistrationForm` Table:

```
public class RegistrationForm
{
    [Key]
    public int RegistrationID { get; set; }
    ...

    // add a navigation property ICollection<Category> to reference the categories
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Next, the `Category` class:

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    //Navigation property to reference the RegistrationForms
    public virtual ICollection<RegistrationForm> RegistrationForms { get; set; }
}
```

next, in your DbContext:  **note** the change in pluralization, and the removal of the `RegistrationCategory`, you do not need a model class for it at all.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<RegistrationForm> RegistrationForms { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<RegistrationForm>()
        .HasMany(r => r.Categories)
        .WithMany(c => c.RegistrationForms)
        .Map(
            m =>
            {
              m.MapLeftKey("RegistrationID");
              m.MapRightKey("CategoryID");
              m.ToTable("RegistrationCategory");
            }
        );
}
```

With this in place, you can now query all the `Categories` of a `RegistrationForm` or all the `RegistrationForms` of a `Category`.

```
foreach (var category in registrationForm.Categories)
{
    //do whatever with each category
}
```

Comment: how to bind `Categories` using `@Html.ListBox` in the view? I have take that data in a separate `List` in a `ViewModel` class? How to save multiple selected categories?

Comment: yes, `Categories` would need to be a list in your ViewModel.  if you sent the entire List to the View, and received back a subset, you could loop through the subset and add each member to the list on the registrationForm object.  If you aren't sure how to implement that, it's probably more appropriate as a whole new question.

Comment: so to read selected values from the `ListBox`, I have to declare a `List<int>` property, bind it to the `ListBox`, loop through the selected values and add new items in `ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }` and finally call .Add() and SaveChanges() methods on the context?

Comment: The Listbox can be bound to a `List<Category>` and the selected items can be another `List<Category>`... you don't even really have to loop through, just assign the `registrationForm.Categories = selection`, unless you want to do anything with the list....

Comment: I have created two `List<Category>` properties in my ViewModel class,  `public List<Category> Categories { get; set; },
        public List<Category> SelectedCategories { get; set; }` one to bind the master data and one to get the selected categories and I have created `ListBox` using `@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedCategories, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName"))`, but I am getting 0 values on `POST` in `SelectedCategories` property...

Comment: ok, this is definitely stretching into another question, not related to the database mapping, more on how to send and receive data from your form.  I'll keep trying to help with any new question you post, but trying to troubleshoot new questions created after implementing an answer using comments isn't really feasible....